# JBoss standalone.xml file changes are being overridden

Tags: java, xml, logging, jboss

We am using JBoss 7 in our project and have written the logging configuration in `standalone.xml` file like this,

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.0">
        .
        .
        .
        <logger category="com.xyz.abc.aspect">
            <level name="DEBUG"/> 
            <handlers>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        .
        .
    </subsystem>
```

Now a situation has arose that i wanted to change the logging configuration by adding `use-parent-handlers="false"` to avoid the log being redirected to parent handler , now when i add this to standalone.xml

```
 <logger category="com.xyz.abc.aspect" use-parent-handlers="false">
                <level name="DEBUG"/> 
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
```

and restart the server the logging configuration is reverted back by JBoss to the previous state i.e

```
<logger category="com.xyz.abc.aspect">
                <level name="DEBUG"/> 
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
```

I have tried deleting **standalone_xml_history** directory and files under it , but nothing is preventing the overwriting behaviour, can any one please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure, but restarting the server probably causes a write-back action of the config. That means your config gets overwritten by with the "current" config the server knows which is the version before you edited the file.
You could simply use the management console

> confguration > core > logging

or use the CLI

> /subsystem=logging/logger=change.me.please:write-attribute(name="use-parent-handlers", value="false")

to make those changes.

Alternatively change the config file when the server is stopped.

Comment: Does that mean that standalone.xml cannot be modified while running the server? I mean, changes done to it would not be "seen" by JBoss? Thank you.

Comment: Yap. Offline edit is not the recommended way anyway. Using the Cli or the admin interface will persist the changes back to the config file. Keep in mind that some changes require a restart in order to be effective.

Comment: @janinee :: I am doing the changes by stopping the server only

Comment: @janinee :: I tried with this command but it says 
`{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "No known attribute called use-parent-handlers",
    "rolled-back" => true
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update **standalone.initial.xml** in **standalone_xml_history** directory. Then restart Jboss, your changes would take place.

reference- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Configuration%20file%20history.html